# How does Git record (or more likely, represent) file paths and names for its blobs, and then identify renames?

Tags: git

I'm trying to get my head around the way that git manages to 'remember' a file's name and its path, given that it only stores file content within a blob. Is the explanation in [link here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/495049117/git-objects-the-commit) by Abizem a good one? (it's the best I've seen so far)

The follow up question, is how does (where) git then determine when we have similarity, especially after a 'move' or path-name update? (as per my Q [sub-directory renames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898080/how-to-work-with-subdirectory-renames-in-git)). I need to be able to maintain an existing workflow that uses path renames as part of low level personal VCS (we have a big iron VCS for big releases, but nothing for day to day / hour to hour use)

Answer (score 10):

`git` defines four kinds of objects (Commit, Tag, Tree, Blob). Each object is identified after the hash of its content.

The three objects that are involved with renaming are :

1. blob: this correspond to a committed file, the content of the object is the compressed content of the original file
2. tree: this correspond to a directory listing, it contains a mapping of filename to other objects (either blobs or trees) and also record the access rigths
3. commit: this contains the commit message, a pointer to the parent commit(s) (except for the first commit), and to a tree object

So when you rename a file and commit it, a new tree object is created (well, and more than one if it is in a subdirectory) with a new mapping name to object, but the object is the same.

However, git does not track rename, it try to rediscover them by comparing file content. If two file are really similar, but have different names, it consider it is a rename. This can be time consuming, and if there are lots of file, it can fail.

Edit: Take a look to the Git Community Book, that has a [really good explanation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) on how does git store information.

Comment: I had a read of the Community book before I posted, and it doesn't directly answer the question. It hints in various places, but never actually says "here is how (the mechanism) we store the path and file name". This may be one a case where those that know think the book's explanation is sufficient, but those that don't can't see it - Is there a place to submit a contribution for discussion?

Comment: The content of the file is detailed here : http://book.git-scm.com/7_browsing_git_objects.html
Hope this help you to understand it.

Comment: @sylvian D: Actually, it (git-scm) supports both our claims. In the Ch 7 RAW GIT section on Creating Trees, it shows that`git mktree` can make arbitary trees (which was the viewpoint I'd picked up), whilst the other sections (e.g. Ch1 Tree Object) talk of a _general_ match between directories and trees (rather than an exact 1:1 match at the Porcelain level). I'll try and draft a paragraph for Git-Scm while I still have the 'clarity' of the first time reader;-)

Answer (score 2):

[**Why does git not "track" renames?**](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F)

> Git has to interoperate with a lot of
>   different workflows, for example some
>   changes can come from patches, where
>   rename information may not be
>   available. Relying on explicit rename
>   tracking makes it impossible to merge
>   two trees that have done exactly the
>   same thing, except one did it as a
>   patch (create/delete) and one did it
>   using some other heuristic.
>
> On a second note, tracking renames is
>   really just a special case of tracking
>   how content moves in the tree. In some
>   cases, you may instead be interested
>   in querying when a function was added
>   or moved to a different file. By only
>   relying on the ability to recreate
>   this information when needed, Git aims
>   to provide a more flexible way to
>   track how your tree is changing.
>
> However, this does not mean that Git
>   has no support for renames. The diff
>   machinery in Git has support for
>   automatically detecting renames, this
>   is turned on by the '-M' switch to the
>   git-diff-* family of commands. The
>   rename detection machinery is used by
>   git-log(1) and git-whatchanged(1), so
>   for example, 'git log -M' will give
>   the commit history with rename
>   information. Git also supports a
>   limited form of merging across
>   renames. The two tools for assigning
>   blame, git-blame(1) and
>   git-annotate(1) both use the automatic
>   rename detection code to track
>   renames.
>
> As a very special case, 'git log'
>   version 1.5.3 and later has '--follow'
>   option that allows you to follow
>   renames when given a single path. 
>   Mail by Linus on this topic.
>
> Git has a rename command git mv, but
>   that is just for convenience. The
>   effect is indistinguishable from
>   removing the file and adding another
>   with different name and the same
>   content.

I am surprised that no one has linked to [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). Much of my learnings are from that.

Also, if you can get the book `Version Control with Git`, do it. It is a very good book, especially for beginners.
Here is the link - [Version Control with Git](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/version-control-with/9781449345037/).
There is also [Git from bottom up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf).

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of including the -M option into the way the Git Gui presents its 'rescan' diff? I need to find a method which shows such changes as renames so that the users accept Git, rather than rejecting it...