# What is the difference between a tree and a directory?

Tags: git, terminology

I am a git novice trying to sort through the concepts and terms. The git glossary says a tree is equivalent to a directory and a directory is what you get with ls. Are they interchangeable terms? Or are "tree" and "directory" to be used in different contexts or to refer to separate (though related) things?

Comment: I had the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917738/how-does-git-record-or-more-likely-represent-file-paths-and-names-for-its-blob - The commit tree structure is/does match the directory structure of the files contained in the commit, but excludes 'empty' directories with nothing to track. Checking out a branch will create any needed directories, but won't delete any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: yes, a tree is a directory and a directory is a tree.

The long answer: A tree is an object that contains a list of blobs, the names to attach to the blobs, and other trees and the names to attach to them. http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html has a pretty good explanation of the different object types in the git model; I would suggest reading it!

Comment: Yes, understanding that the tree references blobs was key.

Answer (score 3):

In Git terminology, a "tree" is a hierarchical structure of files and directories. This is (purposefully) very similar to a directory in a filesystem.

A Git commit object contains a reference to a tree object, which is the state of all files at the time of that commit.

Answer (score 1):

- [The Git Object Model](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html)
- [All Git Object Types: Blob, Tree, Commit And Tag](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/all-git-object-types-blob-tree-commit-and-tag/)

Comment: The diagrams in the second link were very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Personally, I was able to understand git's object model through the illustrated diagram.

Answer (score -1):

To put it simply, the "tree" refers to the snapshot of the entire repository state at that moment in time (like what you've got for your current code [which is also known as HEAD], of  the repository when the currently checked-out commit was made, etc.)

Directory is just referring to a filesystem directory.

Comment: I scare myself with my parenthesis layering sometimes.

Comment: Not strictly true since a tree contains other trees, which themselves may also belong to trees from previous (and future) commits.

Comment: The tree for some directory and the tree for the same directory in other commit may be the same (same SHA1). So a tree may not represent the whole directory and it has nothing to do with time (commits do).