# Git diff for copied files

Tags: git, diff, git-svn

Say I have a file, myfile.txt. It has a paragraph of text in it, and I copy it to a new file, myfile2.txt.

If I git diff, it will show myfile2.txt as a new file. Okay. Now I replace every occurrence of "the" with "hello" and commit.

The problem I'm having is that after the commit happens, git diff will show all of myfile2.txt as a new file and it will not show me that "the" has been replaced by "hello" everywhere (because as far as it's concerned everything is a new change).

Even if I first commit and push myfile2.txt prior to editing so that the changes are evident, that's not a good solution. It is a problem because if I squash commits down to a feature and commit it, myfile2.txt shows up as a brand new file, whereas I would like to see that those replacements have been made.

Does git have a feature that allows me to track changes in a file that was copied from another, such that a git diff will show me only those modifications and not the added file as a whole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [`git diff -M`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) / [`git diff -C`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question recently about the issue of [directory renames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898080/how-to-work-with-subdirectory-renames-in-git) with similar advice.

There is also the --patience option to have a look at [git-diff-patience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045017/what-is-git-diff-patience-for).