# How to tell Git that it's the same directory, just a different name

Tags: git

After getting past a few hurdles learning Git, I came across a new challenge: Renaming a directory (locally, in the working directory).

When I type `git status`, it lists all the files in the old directory name (that exist with the same exact filenames in the new directory) as **deleted** and the new directory name as "untracked".

Is there a way to tell Git that "it's actually the same directory, just a different name"?

So that all the files will be listed by  `git status` as modified only?

To exemplify the problem, here is the output I receive from `git status` when I rename an entire directory:

```
git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    old-dir-name/file1
#   deleted:    old-dir-name/file2
#   deleted:    old-dir-name/file3
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   new-dir-name/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
~/sb/ws>
```

Comment: I just tested this and I don't have that problem. On my box, Git successfully identifies that I renamed a folder and continues to track all it's files without reporting anything on `git status`.

Comment: @karlphillip How did you rename the folder? In my case, I deleted it completely and copied from a different source same content but different name. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Probably. I just renamed it with **mv**: `mv folder new_name`. Git is smart enough to detect if you created new files or just renamed a folder. But when you delete the directory and create a new one (even though it has the same files of the previous dir) git thinks that all those files are new. In the future, just rename it with `mv`. I can add this as an answer if you liked it.

Comment: With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), `git status` should now show you the renames (instead of delete/add files). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.comhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/50573107/6309)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All answers here were very helpful on the way to the actual solution for the particular scenario I was facing. I am providing what worked for me in the form of actual steps, hopefully helping others encountering the same challenge:

1. `git mv <old-dir-name>
   <new-dir-name>`
2. `git status` (verify that all files
   marked **renamed**, not "deleted")
3. `git commit -a -m "git mv
   <old-dir-name> <new-dir-name>"`
   (this is a "fake" commit, to prepare
   for the real rename in the next
   steps)
4. `git branch
   git_mv_20110708_1500_DO_NOT_USE`
   ("fake" branch with timestamp
   reminding that we only did this as a
   workaround)
5. `/bin/rm -Rf <new-dir-name>`
6. `cp -Rp .../<new-dir-name> .` (copy
   over the actual folder with the
   renamed name)
7. `git status` (most modified files
   will now be marked correctly as
   **modified**, not "deleted". Files that have been renamed will be
   marked as deleted *and* added,
   despite having the same content! -- repeated steps 1-7 for those files if rename tracking is needed for them too)
8. `git add <untracked files>`
9. `git commit -a -m "finally renamed
   this folder"`
10. `git branch FOLDER_RENAMED` :)

P.S. `gitk` loves this, but `Emacs` is still confused with the renames. :(

Comment: a bit confusing, in my case my folder was indexed as lowercase but in reality its Uppercase so what works is delete it with its child, commit, create new folder and copy all child, commit again.

Answer (score 20):

Just `git add` the directory at its new name. Git doesn't explicitly track renames, it just detects them later. `git mv` might be marginally more efficient to perform (because it can update the index directly), but the effect is exactly the same.

Comment: That's exactly my understanding and why I am asking: Is there a way to tell Git to tack renames? So that if I use `gitk`, for example, to diff between the older name and the newer name, I will be able to do so?

Comment: @WinWin: That would be up to the tool. For example `git diff` has an `-M` option that allows you to specify how much of a file must match for it to show as a rename.

Comment: @hammar That is a great option, I didn't know about it. Is it available for `git status` and `git commit`, too?

Comment: @WinWin: `git status` doesn't seem to support it. It doesn't make much sense for `git commit`. I'm guessing you'd want it for `-a`, but that won't work. Just `git add` the new/moved directory. Any tool that would detect a rename will detect this as a rename. Git doesn't know the difference.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use git's mv: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html

```
git mv old_dir new_dir
```

So you'll need to move the new dir back to the old, and re-move it with mv.

**EDIT:** To answer the responses to my answer:

I decided to test this out myself. I created two files with distinct text, and used `git mv` on one, and `mv file file2`, `git add file2`, `git add -u` on the other. Commit message indicated that both were tracked as renames. Therefore, all my advice does is save a step, as others were saying.

Comment: This is equivalent to just doing `git rm` on the old file names and `git add` on the new ones. Git tracks content, not changes. The changes are inferred on-demand when you ask for them.

Comment: @d_r_w My understanding from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094269/whats-the-purpose-of-git-mv/1094392#1094392) is `git mv` is only a shorthand that results in the same problem: If I use `gitk` to diff between the new version and the new name, I can't because they are listed as two different files.

Comment: try a `git diff -M`, and see that it detects the renames.

Answer (score 2):

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) should to detect "that it's the same directory, just a different name", because "`git status`" learned to pay attention to UI related diff configuration variables such as `diff.renames`.

See [commit dc6b1d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc6b1d92ca9c0c538daa244e3910bb8b2a50d959) (04 May 2018) by [Eckhard S. Maaß (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1e174fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e174fdbe6b0bea58d20e451ca66a1bbb5829307), 23 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `wt-status`: use settings from `git_diff_ui_config`
>
> If you do something like:
>
> ```
> - git add .
> - git status
> - git commit
> - git show (or git diff HEAD)
> ```
>
> one would expect to have analogous output from `git status` and `git show` (or similar diff-related programs).
> This is generally not the case, as `git status` has hard coded values for diff related options.
>
> With this commit the hard coded settings are dropped from the status
> command in favour for values provided by `git_diff_ui_config`.
>
> What follows are some remarks on the concrete options which were hard
> coded in `git status`:
>
> ```
> diffopt.detect_rename
> ```
>
> Since the very beginning of `git status` in [a3e870f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3e870f2e2bcacc80d5b81d7b77c15a7928a9082) ("Add "commit"
> helper script", 2005-05-30, Git v0.99), `git status` always used rename detection,
> whereas with commands like show and log one had to activate it with a
> command line option.
> After [5404c11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5404c116aa921d7e2f9408e103c80b7801735d08) ("diff: activate `diff.renames` by
> default", 2016-02-25, Git v2.9.0) the default behaves the same by coincidence, but changing `diff.renames` to other values can break the consistency between
> `git status` and other commands again.
> With this commit one control the same default behaviour with `diff.renames`.
>
> ```
> diffopt.rename_limit
> ```
>
> Similarly one has the option `diff.renamelimit` to adjust this limit for
> all commands but `git status`. With this commit `git status` will also honor
> those.

---

And the same Git 2.18 offers `status.renames`, which could be useful for those who want to do so without disabling the default rename detection done by the
"`git diff`" command.

See [commit e8b2dc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8b2dc2c2a8415bfd180ecf5cc237a54e69ac2e9) (11 May 2018) by [Ben Peart (`benpeart`)](https://github.com/benpeart).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5da4847](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5da4847dccdf8df26f0cfbcc278034a62dbc97e0), 30 May 2018)</sup>

> ### add status config and command line options for rename detection
>
> After performing a merge that has conflicts `git status` will, by default,
> attempt to detect renames which causes many objects to be examined.
> In a virtualized repo, those objects do not exist locally so the rename logic
> triggers them to be fetched from the server. This results in the status call
> taking hours to complete on very large repos vs seconds with this patch.
>
> Add a new config `status.renames` setting to enable turning off rename
> detection during status and commit.
> This setting will default to the value of diff.renames.
>
> Add a new config `status.renamelimit` setting to to enable bounding the time
> spent finding out inexact renames during status and commit.
> This setting will default to the value of `diff.renamelimit`.
>
> Add `--no-renames` command line option to status that enables overriding the
> config setting from the command line.
> Add `--find-renames[=<n>]` command line option to status that enables detecting renames and optionally setting the similarity index.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is a User interface / User experience problem, rather than a 'real' problem for git. I've asked the same question [how-to-work-with-subdirectory-renames-in-git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898080/how-to-work-with-subdirectory-renames-in-git) and an underlying question [how-does-git-record-or-more-likely-represent-file-paths-and-names-for-its-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917738/how-does-git-record-or-more-likely-represent-file-paths-and-names-for-its-blob)

In fact Git doesn't actually care. All the messages you (we) get are about what 'diff' thinks might have happened. With other options the messages will be different but the repository won't be any different (it's the same snapshot!).

One option style is the `subtree` option for diff (though it is for a different purpose), as is `--patience`.

There is a need for a better UI/UX option that would more easily detect pathchanges (based on the trees rather than the blobs). Part of the problem is [the subtle mistake](https://web.archive.org/web/20160203033017/http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/217) in Linus's argument. He is right that the Git repo should **not** store the rename (pathchange) explicitly, rather we need an option to allow it's proper discovery.